# Upgrade provisioned Joyent SmartMachine

Tags: smartos, joyent

I am currently running a provisioned Joyent SmartMachine base64 version 1.8.2 with some standard software (apache, php) installed.

Is ist possible to make an upgrade to a newer version (for example to SmartMachine base64 1.9.1) without provisioning a new SmartMachine and then transferring all installed packages and data to that SmartMachine manually?

I would be interested if there was a possibility to do a 'distribution-like upgrade'.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to upgrade from one base image to another. You would have to provision a new base image and migrate what you have over.

However, you can update an existing base image to a newer pkgsrc release though. That tends to be what people typically want, access to the newer packages.

There are instructions on how to do that here:

http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/jpc2/pkgsrc+Releases#pkgsrcReleases-UpdatingthepkgsrcRepository

Before doing that I would strongly recommend **taking a snapshot** of your current machine first so you can roll back if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

> We believe that re-provisioning is just better practise.  It enforces a
>      separation of configuration and data, and encourages the use of high
>      level configuration management tools to design and workflow your
>      deployments.  On the contrary, applying blind updates to an existing
>      install very quickly turns it into a black box, with no way to fully
>      understand the dependencies involved and making it almost impossible to
>      be able to replicate that environment from a clean install.
>    - https://www.mail-archive.com/smartos-discuss@lists.smartos.org/msg00756.html

So you should better learn some Ansible, Puppet or Chef, I guess.